# Reduction of Boolean expression

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

> Reduce the following Boolean expression: $q’ (r’s + rs) + qrs$.

$$\begin{align}
q' (r's + rs) + qrs\quad&\\
q’r’s + q’rs + qrs\quad&\text{distributive law}\\
q’ (r’s + rs) + qrs\quad&\\
s (q’r’ + q’r + qr)\quad &\text{distributive law}\\
s (q’ (r’ + r) + qr)\quad&\text{distributive law}\\
s (q’1 + qr)\quad&\text{inverse law}\\
s(q’ + qr)\quad&\text{identity law}\\
sq' + sqr\quad&\text{distributive law}
\end{align}$$
Is there any way to reduce this further? Since absorption law doesn't apply I haven't found any other laws that could reduce this expression anymore. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reduce it further. Let's start one line before your last line:

$$\begin{align}
s(q’ + qr)\quad&\text{identity law}\\
s(q' + q)(q'+r)\quad&\text{distributive law}\\
s1(q'+r)\quad&\text{inverse law}\\
s(q'+r)\quad&\text{identity law}\\
sq'+sr\quad&\text{distributive law}\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

$$
r's+rs=s \Rightarrow q'(r's+rs) = q's
$$